# Make OpenOffice Portable the Default Program?

Tags: windows-7, windows, openoffice

How do I make OpenOffice.org *portable* be my default document viewer on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on a document and select 'Open with...'. There should be a checkbox to open with that program every time.

By the way, OpenOffice.org has forked after the Oracle takeover. Take a look at [this news article](http://blogs.computerworld.com/17197/oracle_kicks_libreoffice_supporters_out_of_openoffice) and [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/).

Comment: (1) That's not the proper way to do it, I need to get it to show up as a real application in the Default Programs control panel item. That method doesn't "really" work, it's just a workaround. (2) Yeah I've tried LibreOffice but I really don't mind continuing to use OO. :)

Comment: 1. I don't see what is improper about this.

2. OO.o basically has no developers left. If you want maintained code, better switch to LibreOffice.

Comment: 1. It doesn't set the "true" default, it's just a temporary fix for the *file type* rather than for the *application*. Underneath the hood, in the registry, it's an ugly hack with file extensions, that still leaves traces of the old default in many cases... I've just grown to dislike this solution over time, because of the problems it causes later.
2. Okay, I'll think about it, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use portable apps a lot, and I think the best way to make file associations (even permanently) is by using `Portable File Associator`, which is programmed using AutoIt (yeah!).  Unfortunately, I cannot find a working download link for it.  I do plan to make my own modifications to it soon.  I can give you a direct download link from my computer if you are interested in using it.

An alternative is [eXpresso](http://portableapps.com/node/22677), which is made using AutoHotKey (boo!).  I do not like the way this one works that much, as it intercepts clicks rather than making registry entries in HKCU.